# IBM Content Collector FS to P8 Archiving

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, ibm-content-collector

In my current project using IBM Content Collector 4.0.1 SP5 with IBM Filenet P8 Content Engine 5.2.1 I need to collect files from file system and add them to a certain P8's object store.

Report files are added into folders eight fixed folders and under them the structure grows dinamically over time with further nested folders following the form yyyy/mm:

[image: Folder hierarchy]

I started from the `FS to P8 Archiving (Replicate File System and Detect Duplicates).ctms` task route example in order to have the replicated structure in my object store.

[image: FS to P8 Archiving task route]
Let's focus on the `P8 File Document in folder task` and particularly on the `File in Folder Options`.

The problem is that the path created in my repository contains also the drive letter (e.g.: `E:\Report\AMM_000001_00001\2017\05`) whereas I would like to have only the folder structure replicated starting from the Report folder.

How can I achieve this?
Should I use regular expressions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve the desired result using regular expressions in the "P8 File Document In Folder" task, like this:

> ```
> Purpose:            Get a folder path without a drive letter. 
> Regular expression: ^[^\\]* 
> Replacement string: $1 
> Sample text:        C:\folder 1\folder 2 
> Sample result:      \folder 1\folder 2
> ```

as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAE9L_3.0.0/com.ibm.content.collector.doc/expression_editor/r_afu_regular_expression_samples.htm).